# Filtering my DataGridView in Master-Detail type form with entity framework

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-6, master-detail

**My Problem:**

[This is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3oRs.jpg)

I would like to just filter out same ID rows

Barely any code to show pretty much dragged and dropped entity-es and did some customizing.

Toolstrip and datagrid are binded to same source

**My Goal:**

[I would like my form to filter out only the rows with same ID as ID in textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZrFq.jpg) when I navigate with toolbox buttons

My thoughts so far: Perhaps I can make a query where ID in textbox matches ID in first column and weed out those rows and just display them. But how would that keep the format I have? Comboboxes etc.. some columns have different binding sources, for example column #2, column#3 are have different binding sources as opposed to column#1(to which i'm trying to filter rows) and column#4,5

**Edit**: I have tried following

```
nastavniPlanProgramDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in nastavniPlanProgramDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if(row.Index!=rowIndex)
            {
                row.Selected = false;
                row.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(row.Index==rowIndex)
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                    row.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

> However i keep encountering an error when executing `row.Visible=false;`

Comment: Please don't post the answer as an edit in your question. It's confusing for future readers. If you think the answer may help future readers, post it as a comment or as an answer if it has enough description.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply adding the following before executing the above code-snippet in the question.

```
AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```